# EF Code first cannot locate database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have created a service which is fetching some data and being stored into the database. 
While fetching the data or storing the data, I can see data is being stored properly but I am unable to see the Database anywhere.

My connection string and context are as follows

```
public class Context: DbContext 
{
    public DBContext() : base("name=DBConnectionString") 
    {
        public DbSet<IEmployee> Employees {get; set;}
    }
}


 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=SLDB;Integrated Security=true" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

DB isn't appearing in SQL server object explorer neither I can find it on physical file system.

I have looked at following location for physical/mdf file already

- c:\user\HaseebAsif
- %AppData%(roaming/local)\Microsoft....
- c:\Program Files\Microsoft\Microsoft sql server ....

When I connect to server using '(localdb)/v11.0', it just shows the system database, not mine, SLDB.

Any idea how can I see the database in SSMS or in windows explorer

Comment: try to remove `name=`

Comment: at the moment I have three different instances of SQL (2012,2014) installed and I want my db to be in v11 so I have specified the connection string.

Answer (score 1):

Add `AttachDbFilename=c:\path\todb\SLDB.mdf` to the connection string to both the project holding the EF context/models, etc. and the application itself.

You can also use application domain properties in the connection string as such `|TheVariable|`

Then in your `Configuration.cs` EF class module constructor:

```
public Configuration()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("TheVariable", @"c:\path\todb"); //or something dynamic...
}
```

Do the same at startup of your application and then you can it so:

```
AttachDbFilename=|TheVariable|\SLDB.mdf
```

Do an `Update-database` again, the MDF file will be at the path specified in the connection string.

If the database does not appear in SQL Management Studio at this point, right click the `Database` node and `Attach` the MDF manually.